# Confused about the representation of a basis in $V = M_{2×2}(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, vectors

If the bases of $V = M_{2×2}(\mathbb{R})$ are 2 x 2 matrices, how is it possible that each basis can also be represented as a column matrix?

Comment: The bases of $V$ are NOT *2x2* matrices. A basis is a set. If you have a basis of $V$, then *its elements* are *2x2* matrices. For example,$$\left\{\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix},\,\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix},\,\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{pmatrix},\,\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\right\}$$is a basis of $V$.

Comment: Is it not standard to call elements of a basis set "basis vectors" and/or "bases"?

Comment: "Basis vectors" yes. But not "bases". The latter is the plural of "basis".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This only holds for $K^n$, since you have an isomorphism $(K^n)^n \cong M_n(K)$, where $(a_i)_{i \in \{1,\ldots,n \}} \mapsto (a_1,\ldots, a_n)$ and $a_i$ is a vector in $K^n$. For the dimensions we have $\dim((K^n)^n) =n^2 = \dim(M_n(K))$.

Comment: What function defines the isomorphism? Or are they isomorphic because of the same dimension?

Comment: Any two spaces of same finite dimension are isomorphic. Just take a basis for each one and define a linear transformation that is a bijection between these two bases.

Comment: Check my edit, hope you understand it now